# What is the best way to do if condition in csharp?

Tags: c#

I have the following code that works:

```
if (user.ReAccess == 1 || user.CetAccess == 1)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            //Do Something
        }
```

But, ideally I would like to do something like this (if not).  But this has syntax error.

```
if !(user.ReAccess == 1 || user.CetAccess == 1)
        {
    //Do Something
        }
```

Comment: You can make it work, just add some parentheses

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most direct way would be to do this:

```
if (!(user.ReAccess == 1 || user.CetAccess == 1))
```

But thanks to De Morgan's law, we could rewrite it like this:

```
if (user.ReAccess != 1 && user.CetAccess != 1)
```

Comment: I usually role with the former as it is easier to read. In it we are declaring the case that we are rejecting explicitly.

Comment: I tend to use the former as well. I agree that I find it more readable. That said +1 for a more complete answer.

Comment: @Gusdor To a point it's personal preference, although some specific situations just make more sense with one or the other.

Comment: Yes, `a || b = !(!a && !b)` and also `a && b = !(!a || !b)`.

Answer (score 2):

Surround it with braces:

```
if (!(user.ReAccess == 1 || user.CetAccess == 1))
{
    //Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use not equal to operator

```
 if (user.ReAccess != 1 && user.CetAccess != 1)
    {
        //Do Something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
if (!(user.ReAccess == 1 || user.CetAccess == 1))
    {
//Do Something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DeMorgans.  If `A = 1 || B = 1` same as  `A != 1 && B != 1`, so;

```
if (user.ReAccess != 1 && user.CetAccess 1= 1)
   {
      // Do Something
   }
```